# Doesn't contain a default export even I correctly contain default export in React

Tags: reactjs, export

I just get started learning React, so I am sorry if I asked so basic question. I tried to solve this error message 'doesn't contain a default export(imported as 'Main') even though I write the bottom of the file export default Main. Could you check for me which part do I miss?

I will share my code below

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./Main.css";

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="wrapper"> 
                    <div class="nav">
                        <p class="logo"> Westagram </p>
                        <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search", style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />
                        <div class="icons">
                            <img id="compass" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/explore.png" />
                            <img id="heart" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/heart.png" /> 
                            <img id="my-page" src=" https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/profile.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="main">
                        <div class="feeds">
                            <div class="article">
                                <div class="identi">
                                    <img class="selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" /> 
                                    <span class="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>
                                    
                                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="pic">
                                    <img src="../src/images/ucscPic.png" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="show-box">
                                    <div class="reaction-icons">
                                        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="like-counts">
                                        <span>like 4,000</span>
                                    <div>

                                    <div class="check-comments">
                                        <span>UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely or online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person instruction for a small</span>
                                        <a id="space" href="">expanding</a><br />
                                        <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                                        <ul class="feed-comments">
                                            <li>test</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment">
                                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                                    <input class="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Add Comment..." />
                                    <button class="post">Post</button>
                                </div>
 
                                
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-right">
                        <div class="top">
                            <img class="selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" />
                            <div class="main-right-name">
                                <span id="eng-name">JiwanJeon94</span><br />
                                <span id="kr-name">전지완</span>
                            </div>
                            
                            <a href="">Transform</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="middle">
                            <div class="middle-words">
                                <span id="recommendation">Suggestions For You</span>
                                <a href="" id="view-all">view all</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="recommendation-people">
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>  
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>                  
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>                                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="footer">
                            <div class="footer-top">
                                <a  href="">About</a>
                                <a  href="">Help</a>            
                                <a  href="">press</a>
                                <a  href="">API</a>     
                                <a  href="">Jobs</a>        
                                <a  href="">Privacy</a> 
                                <a  href="">Terms</a>   
                                <a  href="">Locations</a>       
                                <a  href="">TopAccounts</a> 
                                <a  href="">Hashtags</a>    
                                <a  href="">Language</a><br /><br />    
                        </div>              
                        <span>2021 INSTAGRAM FROM FACEBOOK</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make sure all of your html tags are closed correctly. E.g. with the `.like-counts` div, you are closing it with a `<div>` element rather than a `</div>`. Also make sure all of your line breaks are self closing. E.g. use `<br />` rather than `<br>`. Opening the code in an editor like VS-code is quite helpful and will highlight some of the mistakes you've made.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I closed all div tag with /div and br /. I also check in vs code but... I am not sure... why it does still show the same error message..

Comment: Have you also removed the comma in the `.search-box` input (after the `placeholder` attribute)? If there are no red error indicators in VS code, it would be helpful to know a bit more about the running code e.g. which version of node/npm are you using? Are you using Babel at all? Did you create this using create-react-app? You may be on a version that doesn't support ES6 syntax, in which case you would need to use `module.exports = Main` instead of `export default Main`

Comment: Oh when I change the file to jsx, It shows 'div' has no corresponding closing tag. in vs code. At the top of div and wrapper div and main div. However, I closed with the closing tag below but I am not sure why the vs code didn't catch it...

Comment: Ah yes sorry I forgot to point that out - you'll need to have your editor set to either jsx or tsx (if using typescript) to find these errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out @matt.main! You save my time! :) I struggling with this problem for few hours :(